# Modify STARTUPINFO after CreateProcess

Tags: windows, winapi

I would like to be able to change the `STARTUPINFO` values, right **after** `CreateProcess` has been called (suspended).

So the new remote/child process can get custom `GetStartupInfo` values as soon as it starts.

How could I achieve this?

More Info:

I would like to pass arbitary data to the child process.
Regarding to this article: http://www.catch22.net/tuts/undocumented-createprocess it is possible to do so with the `reserved2` members from the `STARTUPINFO` structure. This method works but has a limit of 65536 bytes. A theoretical solution in order to pass more than 65536 bytes would be if you:

1. Create the process (suspended)
2. Alloc space with `VirtualAllocEx` in the child process
3. Write data > 65536 bytes to the child process with `WriteProcessMemory`
4. Change the `reserved2` members with the address from Step 2
5. Resume the process
6. The child process calls `GetStartupInfo` and gets the data

Comment: The obvious thing to do is to change the values before you call `CreateProcess`. Presumably that's not an option because you aren't calling `CreateProcess`. Which makes me think that there's some external process, injection, hooking trickery going on. Would it help if we knew what that was?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are correct. I would like to extend/break the `lpReserved2` limit which is 65536 bytes. If I was able to fill this value with the result of a previous `VirtualAllocEx` call, I could theoretically store as much bytes as RAM has to offer.

Comment: I don't really understand that comment. All the same, I think that you should edit the question to add some more details. Perhaps somebody will have a different way to solve your root problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have edited my question.

Comment: Why don't you use standard IPC to let the other process know where to find this memory?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because you need to allocate a window handle, etc. I would prefer if my "idea" would work by simply changing the value of this member.

Comment: You don't need a window handle. Memory mapped file would be perfect for this. The docs are clear on `lpReserved2`. Don't use it. Pass the name the file mapping as a command line argument and it's all good.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any supported way for you to do what you ask. However, I suggest an alternative solution to the root problem.

1. You should not be using `lpReserved2` anyway since the documentation tells you to set it to `NULL`.
2. Have the parent process create a named memory mapped file.
3. Pass the name of this file mapping to the child process as a command line argument.

Indeed, there are many variants on this approach, but command line arguments are the way to pass information to a new process.